# Create Tomcat User without username and encrypted password for Basic Authentication

Tags: tomcat, basic-authentication

I'm using Tomcat for HTTP Basic Authentication and everything is working fine. I was just wondering if i could improve things a little bit.

Is is possible to create a tomcat user with no username?

```
<tomcat-users>
<role rolename="admin"/>
<user username="admin1" password="adminpassword1" roles="admin"/>
<user password="someApiKey" roles="admin"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

I wanted to enable authentication by just sending an API key, so the username would not be necessary anymore. But when i try a `curl (-u someApiKey:)` i get the message "This request requires HTTP authentication".

And is there a better way to store the passwords? Plaintext in an XML file seems not secure for me. In databases I always used hash and salt.

Answer (score 0):

Use tomcat/bin/digest.sh to create an encrypted password that you can include in tomcat-users.xml.

Comment: anyway he will need an username?